# How to install apt-get and debian packages on busybox

Tags: docker, debian, busybox

I've recently download the busybox image from dockerhub [busybox:glibc - Debian](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox/), and notice that `apt-get` is not available on this distribution. I tried to install debian packages through https://packages.debian.org/stable/ but with no success.

Could please someone explain me how to handle this situation, and how to install `apt-get` on busybox. It there any way to install debian packages on it ?

BR
Arthur Silva

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned `busybox:glibc` is only built against glibc from debian, it is not derived from it. It just contains busybox and the libc, nothing else. Thus you don't have apt, or any package manager installed. If you really need apt, then please take `debian` as base image.

You can take a look at it: https://github.com/docker-library/busybox/tree/dist-amd64/glibc